# Vmplayer drag and drop issue from guest to host

Tags: vmware, drag-and-drop

I am having an issue with the drag and drop feature of VMware Workstation Player 15. I have vmtools installed as well, but perhaps there is an issue with the installation I am unaware of. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and running Windows 7 on the virtual machine. I am able to drag and drop any file from the host (Ubuntu) to the guest (Windows) without a problem; however, I cannot drag and drop from the guest (Windows) to the host (Ubuntu).

Most similar issues I have found related to this have the opposite issue, that is, the drag and drop from host to guest does not work while the guest to host does.

Here is an example of an error message I receive when I try to copy the example file "abstract art.pdf" from the guest to the host (vmplayer is run with sudo permissions):

> Error while copying "abstract art.pdf". 
> There was an error copying the
>   file into /home/user/Desktop. 
> Error opening file
>   /var/run/vmblock-fuse/blockdir/ZnLFWa/abstract art.pdf: Permission
>   denied

What do I have to do to allow permissions for copying a file from the guest to the host system?

Answer (score 0):

I would be keen to know how to fix that too. I have added into the `.vmx` file the following:

```
isolation.tools.copy.disable = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.dnd.disable = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.paste.disable = "FALSE" 
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
```

but it only fixed the issue with some files, whereas the other files still trigger the error.

Comment: seems to be a partial answer that might help someone